# Могу ли я купить аккаунт разработчика Google по валюте своей страны?

Tags: google-play

Хотел бы зарегистрировать аккаунт разработчика Google Play. Могу ли я оплатить регистрацию по валюте Казахстана(будет ли Google автоматический делать конвертацию валюты) или нужен долларовый счет?

Comment: На сколько мне известно, то можно в любой валюте вносить. Оно должно само перевести валюту

Comment: Это не проблема гугла. Это задача банка, в котором Вы обслуживаетесь. Вот там и спросите. Вполне может быть, что банк проведет платеж, но только если Вы специально попросите банк разрешить подобные операции.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его надо адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я оплачивал украинской гривной - все работает!